# Documenting ctypes fields

Tags: python, documentation

I am working on a python module that is a convenience wrapper for a c library. A python `Simulation` class is simply a ctypes structure with a few additional helper functions. Most parameters in `Simulation` can just be set using the `_fields_` variable. I'm wondering how to document these properly. Should I just add it to the `Simulation` docstring? Or should I write getter/setter methods just so I can document the variables?

Comment: If _ever_ you find yourself tempted to write getter/setter methods in Python you should stop & ask yourself "Do I ***really*** need this?"; the answer will rarely be "Yes". Adding them just so you have something to hang docstrings off is **not** a good reason, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do similar things, if it is a small class I will put everything in the same class, but if it is bigger, I typically make a class that only contains the fields, and then a subclass of that with functions.  Then you can have a docstring for your fields class and a separate docstring for your simulation functions.

YMMV, but I would never consider adding getters and setters for the sole purpose of making the documentation conform to some real or imaginary ideal.